# How can I constrain an object's movement inside an ellipse?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, rendertransform

### The scenario

I have several objects in a grid. I translate them inside their manipulation delta event. The objects appear stuck under the user's pointer. It works, and looks something like this:

```
ellipse.ManipulationDelta += (s, e) =>
{
    var transform = ellipse.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    transform.TranslateX = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
    transform.TranslateY = e.Cumulative.Translation.Y;
}
```

Every movable object has an elliptical boundary outside of which the object should not be dragged. This value is simple to calculate. Something like this:

```
ellipse.ManipulationDelta += (s, e) =>
{
    var boundary = new Ellipse { Height = 50, Width = 100 };

    var transform = ellipse.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    transform.TranslateX = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
    transform.TranslateY = e.Cumulative.Translation.Y;
};
```

### The requirement

I would like to implement some type of logic that would not translate the element if the requested point is outside the elliptical boundary.

[image]

Something, perhaps like this:

```
ellipse.ManipulationDelta += (s, e) =>
{
    var boundary = new Ellipse { Height = 50, Width = 100 };
    var point = DeterminePoint(boundary, e.Cumulative.Translation);

    var transform = ellipse.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    transform.TranslateX = point.X;
    transform.TranslateY = point.Y;
};

Point DeterminePoint(Ellipse boundary, Point target) { /* TODO */ }
```

I can easily write the code to constrain the logic to a rectangle. But a rectangle is not the requirement, an ellipse is. It's the `TODO` section in the code above that is the heart of this question.

Thank you, in advance.